# Can Session (API) timeout greater than 2 hours?

Tags: soap-api, session

Is there any harm if we configure Session timeout to 12 or 24 hour period when integrating SF with the external systems

Comment: There is no harm even if the access token never expires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integrations, it doesn't matter. Automatic session termination is most useful for preventing accidental unauthorized access by some means. For example, if I open the Data Loader, go on lunch, and forget to log out or lock my workstation, someone else could use my open application to extract data, delete a bunch of data, etc. The same is true of browser logins as well. However, if you're talking about an integration that only ever talks server-to-server, then the risk is minimal, and the session timeout does not matter as much. Ideally, you should customize the session length per profile to minimize risk while maximizing convenience.